# LOIC to work in ubuntu

Tags: security

i have been wondering on using `LOIC(Low Orbit Ion Cannon)` in `ubuntu`,but the problem is will

it work in `ubuntu 13.10` because `LOIC` is developed in `.Net`.

how to get `LOIC` working in `ubuntu`?

Comment: Did you check [Other Implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Orbit_Ion_Cannon#Other_implementations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a deb version of Loiq (the same program, in qt) [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/loiq/files/).

[image]

There's no 64-bit version, but you can install the 32-bit in any system, even ubuntu 64. Just download the package and:

```
sudo dpkg -i loiq*.deb
```